# console.error:"the action navigate with payload...was not handled..."

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

I'm having an issue with the "onLogin" function within the "LoginComponent".  After pressing the TouchableOpacity that handles that function, I want the user to then be directed to the "HomeComponent", but instead I get this console.error: "the action navigate with payload...was not handled..." Anybody know why this is?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeComponent';
import LoginScreen from './LoginComponent';
import RegisterScreen from './RegisterComponent';
import HomeScreen from './HomeComponent';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStackScreen = () => {
    return <AuthStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome">
        <AuthStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <AuthStack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
};

const HomeTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeTabScreen = () => {
    return <HomeTab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <HomeTab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </HomeTab.Navigator>
}

class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
        };
        this.loginStatusCheck();
    }

    loginStatusCheck = async () => {
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userprofile");
        if(userToken) {
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
        } else {
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <NavigationContainer>
                {this.state.isLoggedIn ? <AuthStackScreen /> : <HomeTabScreen />}
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    };
};
export default Navigation;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Linking, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Input, CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

class LoginScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password:"",
            token: "",
            remember: false
        };
        this.getData();
    };

    handleUsernameChange = username => {
        this.setState({ username })
    };

    handlePasswordChange = password => {
        this.setState({ password })
    };

    onLogin = async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("userprofile", JSON.stringify({ username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password }));
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
                screen: "HomeScreen",
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    getData = async () => {
        try { 
            const userprofile = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userprofile");
            const userProfile = JSON.parse(userprofile);
            if (userProfile !== null) {
                this.setState({ ...userProfile })
            }
            if (username !== null) {
                this.setState({ username })
            }
            if (password !== null) {
            this.setState({ password })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { username, password } = this.state;

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Login</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.fillerText}>Hi there! Nice to see you again.</Text>
                    <Input 
                        inputStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                        placeholder="Enter username"
                        onChangeText={this.handleUsernameChange}
                        value={username}
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        leftIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'user-circle-o', color: 'white', marginRight: 10 }}
                    />
                    <Input
                        inputStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry
                        onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
                        value={password}
                        leftIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'lock', color: 'white', marginRight: 10 }}
                    />
                    <CheckBox 
                        title="Remember Me"
                        checked={this.state.remember}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({remember: !this.state.remember})}
                        containerStyle={styles.rememberCheckbox}
                        textStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                        checkedColor="crimson"
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        style={styles.loginButton} 
                        title="Login" type="submit" 
                        onPress={this.onLogin}
                        >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'grey', marginTop: 20}}>
                        OR use an account from one of the following:
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.twitterButton}>
                            <FontAwesome name="twitter" color="white" style={{marginRight: 5}}/>
                            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Twitter</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.facebookButton}>
                            <FontAwesome name="facebook-square" color="white" style={{marginRight: 5}}/>
                            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Facebook</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.googleButton}>
                        <FontAwesome name="google" color="black" style={{marginRight: 5}}/>
                        <Text style={{color: 'grey'}}>Google</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: 75}} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('#')}>
                            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
                                Forgot Your Password?
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: 75, marginLeft: 210}} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('#')}>
                            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
                                Register
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    buttonsContainer: {
        flex: 2,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    linkContainer: {
        flex: 3,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    titleText: {
        fontSize: 26,
        color: 'white',
        marginBottom: 30,
        marginTop: 20
    },  
    fillerText: {
        color: 'grey',
        marginBottom: 20
    },
    loginButton: {
        backgroundColor: 'crimson',
        paddingVertical: 17,
        paddingHorizontal: 25,
        borderRadius: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    twitterButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#00acee',
        marginTop: 20,
        padding: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '40%',
        marginLeft: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    facebookButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#4267B2',
        marginTop: 20,
        padding: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '40%',
        marginLeft: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    googleButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        marginTop: 20,
        padding: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '40%',
        marginLeft: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    rememberCheckbox: {
        margin: 10,
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: null
    }
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: The HomeTabScreen function is supposed to be rendered after checking if this.state.isLoggedIn is true.  The AuthStackScreen function is supposed to be displayed if this.state.isLoggedIn is false, which is what it defaults to prior to authentication. I deal with authentication through Asynchronous Storage in both the LoginComponent.js and NavigationComponent.js.  Does that help clarify anything?

Comment: I think given this structure the `navigate` is unnecessary. The important think is making sure `Navigation` rerenders after you set the user data in async storage. You say `AuthStack` should be shown if  `this.state.isLoggedIn` is `false`, but in your current code that's the other way around.

Comment: Is there maybe an async function I can create within my NavigationComponent.js that can "reload" the app in order to make a Boolean check of this.state.isLoggedIn bc I now see what you're saying in that I don't need that navigation.navigate prop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its necessary to use `navigate` in your `LoginScreen` component, since you've already written code that conditionally renders two navigators based on the value of `isLoggedIn`.

What you're missing in your current implementation is a way to update `isLoggedIn` from within your `LoginScreen` component. Then if `isLoggedIn` is updated and set to `true`, the `Navigation` component will be re-rendered and the `HomeScreen` component is shown without having to navigate.

I've chosen to use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) here, but you could also use this approach with something like redux also if you prefer that. The reason to use something like react context is to be able to easily pass `isLoggedIn` and its setter between components.

I'll give a more general example, because its easier to illustrate the approach that way:

```
// Imports and other stuff...

const LoginContext = React.createContext([null, () => {}]);

const LoginContextProvider = props => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn]}>
      {props.children}
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useContext(LoginContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>LoginScreen</Text>
      <Button
        title="login"
        onPress={() => {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeTabScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const AuthStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const Navigation = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useContext(LoginContext);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? <HomeTabScreen /> : <AuthStackScreen />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <LoginContextProvider>
      <Navigation />
    </LoginContextProvider>
  );
}
```

So the approach shown above is to create a provider that holds your `isLoggedIn` state and setter (`setIsLoggedIn`). Then when we wrap `Navigation` with this provider so we can access `isLogged` and `setIsLoggedIn` from any component inside the provider, allowing us to update the `isLogged` state inside the `LoginScreen` component. When this state updates, the provider and everything inside it (i.e. `Navigation`), will re-render and show the `HomeScreen` component.

---

*Normally the convention is to put most the react context related stuff in its own file and import parts in components where you need them, but for demonstration purposes I haven't done this.*